# ROR: Full Screen Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have tried different options and also the ones posted on stackoverflow. But nothing seems to work. I have logo.png file in /public/images and a custom.css file in stylesheets.

I want the background of every page to be logo.png (full screen)

I tried the following after searching a lot. But i got nothing. The background is just blank.

Please help

```
 body{
 background: url('../images/logo.png') repeat-x ;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 }
```

Comment: Can you see the image if you just navigate to it via the browser? Maybe it's a routes or a permissions issue.

Comment: Try `url('/images/logo.png')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely do NOT want to use repeat-x
To illustrate why, Use the following link http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image and paste the code below and see what happens, then remove the repeat-x and see the results

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  color: white;
  background:url('paper.gif') repeat-x;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hellos World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

If your image is not displaying after remove repeat-x, it will most likely be a path issue (as others have already pointed) out or a bad image.

The only other thing is if there are other classes/divs defined in your css that override the background property that you have set in the body text. Others have suggested you use firebug. I have to whole heartedly agree. Firebug is pretty essential when dealing with HTML and CSS issues.

Firebug is available to Chrome and Firefox browsers (Firefox as a plugin, Chrome by default) but I'm unsure of other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `repeat-x` put `repeat`.
Other than that check if the path to your image is correct.

Comment: That does not work either. The image file is in /public/images/ and the css file is in public/stylesheets/. So i think the path is right.

Comment: Is your CSS clean? Is this the only place where you change background. Also check if there isn't any CSS hardcoded in HTML. Or best yet, check what value does firebug show.

Answer (score 0):

**Path problem ? ^^**

Can you see your image if you just navigate to it ? If not try to use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) to see what is the problem and to solve it easily.

**Full Screen background image :**

I found an interesting [article](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/) on css-tricks may be usefull, the author offers some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JQuery plugin I've used for full screen background images, and it's called [bgStetcher](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-jquery-stretch-background-plugin.html). You can use it to stretch background images to fill the screen. Such a thing cannot be done in CSS.